# How do I install javahl?

Tags: 10.10, installation, eclipse

I'm trying to get Subclipse working in Eclipse Galeilo, and to do that I have to install the JavaHL library.

I installed the library using `sudo apt-get install libsvn-java`, but the eclipse.ini file has to be modified to take in the new library as an argument.

First change to the ini file was `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni/`, which produced the errors
"no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path"
"incompatible javahl library loaded. 1.3.x or later required."
**according to the install printout, version 1.6.12 was installed.**

So, I added `libsvnjavahl-1.so` to the file path above, and produced the following errors:
"no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path"
"no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path"
"no svnjavahl in java.library.path"

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you installing eclipse from ubuntu repository? or download from eclipse?

IMHO you need install eclipse manually.

first you install subversion :

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

if you want to install subversion plugin for eclipse, you can install using menu `Help -> Install New Software` choose Helios or Galileo :

[image: Eclipse Helios]

choose `Collaboration` and select Subversive :

[image: Subversive]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I basically had to reinstall eclipse to get it working, but you got me on the right track

Answer (score 2):

Subversive?  Not a good option, the problem is that version 1.7 or later of JavaHL is required, and the user is correct that libsvn-java only includes 1.6.x.  Ubuntu needs to update this library.

Answer (score 2):

Install svn from WANdisco - worked for me.
Small explanation with solution:

https://plus.google.com/110836571215849032642/posts/5gecVzxXUpz

Script to run (found in the post above too), which will install the subversive and libsvn-java 1.7

http://pastebin.com/H7YjU1c3

And (as specified in the question), add the following line in `eclipse.ini`

`-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni/`

Comment: Matyas has the key points.  Get 1.7 and future svn from wandisco's repository and instruct eclipse on where to find the library.  Otherwise, you'll have 1.7 but won't be able to find JavaHL.   Very nice work.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently this error again, even if I installed `libsvn-java` from years. Not sure if it's due to upgrade to `Eclipse 2019-03` or change to `Azul Zulu 8`.

Anyway, I fixed it adding to `eclipse.ini`, in `-vmargs` options:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/
```

I have **L**ubuntu 18.04.2